# How to handle Windows Forms controls created at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime, controls

I have a `Form` on which there are two controls, a `Button` and a `TextBox`.
These controls are created at runtime.

When I click the `Button`, I want to do some operations with the `TextBox.Text` property.
But, with this code I can't:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     TextBox txb = new TextBox();
     this.Controls.Add(txb);
     Button btn = new Button();
     this.Controls.Add(btn);
     btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
 }
```

Here I'm trying to find it:

```
public void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in this.Controls)
    {
        if (item is TextBox)
        {
            if (((TextBox)item).Name=="txb")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("xxx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a Textbox with Name "txb". so, this expression will always be false: `if(((TextBox)item).Name=="txb")`

try this codes:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     TextBox txb = new TextBox();
     txb.Name = "txb";
     this.Controls.Add(txb);
     Button btn = new Button();
     this.Controls.Add(btn);
     btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would save off a reference to your `TextBox`.

```
TextBox txb;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     txb = new TextBox();
     this.Controls.Add(txb);
     Button btn = new Button();
     this.Controls.Add(btn);
     btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
 }
```